# How To Join Three tables linked with a foreign key And get sum and count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I Create 3 tables, table Customer, Order, Items

Table : Customer

| Emp_ID | Customer_Name | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ronnie | Male |
| 2 | Jammie | Female |

Table : Order

| Emp_ID | Order_Id | Orde_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 24/08/2021 |

Table : Items

| Emp_ID | Order_ID | Items_ID | Items_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 4 | Coffee |
| 1 | 11 | 5 | Milk |
| 1 | 11 | 6 | Coffee |
| 1 | 11 | 7 | Banana |

how to join and linked this 3 tables? How Many Coffee, Milk And Banana Ronnie Order at date 24/08/2021 ? query please

Comment: `Items`  table shouldn't have a foreign key to `Customer`

Comment: you shouldn't name your table ORDER because it is a reserved keyword

Comment: Provide desired output for shown sample data.

Comment: I'm confused.  What is `emp_id` and why is it in all tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is wrong.

One customer can have many orders, and one order should be associated with just one customer. So in this case the table `Order` should have a foreign key to `Customer`.

One order can have many items, and one item can be present in many orders, so you should create an intermediary table (`OrderItems`) with the foreign key of `Orders` and `Items`, and additional attributes related to this relationship (for example, a `quantity`)

The query to get all the attributos for this datamodel, would be something like this:

```
select *
from Orders o
  join Customers c
    on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerID
  join OrderItems oi
    on o.OrderId = oi.OrderId
  join Items i
    on i.ItemId = oi.ItemId
```

Comment: yes, its to join and select view all tables in one, but I need sum total of items grouped by customer, for eg, Ronnie order on date 24/8/2021,  2 coffee,  1 Milk , 1 Banana, how to show in the table ?

Comment: Start by creating this model. Then, create new questions for your newer requirements.

Answer (score 0):

it took me longer time to understand your question but I think I do now.

I would use left join of order, customer and then items and apply grouping to cutomerID.

```
select 
Orde_Date,
cust_ID,
Items_Type,
count(Items_Type)
from
order ord
left join customer cust on ord.cust_ID = cust.Emp_ID
left_join Items ite on ite.cust_ID = ite.Emp
order by Orde_Date,Cust_ID, Items_Type
```

this is assuming emp_ID is customer_ID on customer table and order ID is unique for all customers.